# Why does dottrace significantly improves startup time of my web application?

Tags: dottrace

I am trying to find out why my web application (.NET + Sitecore) takes so long to start, but dottrace makes it start faster.

The current startup time is about 270 seconds, but when I start application with dottrace it actually takes 30 seconds. This is reproducible every time including other developers machines.

I am using .NET 4 and IIS 10 (app pool runs as Network Service).

Answer (score 0):

The performance depends on the Windows Kernel Timer resolution, and dotTrace changes the value of this timer to the minimum possible value. So if dotTrace makes your program faster, it may indicate that (for example) there are many Thread.Sleep(n) calls in your program, where "n" is a relatively small number (1-5-10-20 milliseconds). Do you have such calls in your application?

Comment: That is an interesting insight. There is no Thread.Sleep calls in my app codebase (however they may exist in referenced assemblies). 

Could you please share the source of your knowledge regarding dotTrace changing timer resolution?

Comment: Sure - I'm a member of dotTrace developing team :)

Comment: @KonKat This comes almost 4 years late, but I recently noticed something similar, and tracked it down to the compilation steps IIS performs the first time you launch a site. If you then stop and restart the site, the IIS part of the startup time disappears almost entirely, but if you make even a trivial change to the code and recompile, the long startup delay is back.